# Verificar REQUEST

Tags: php, soap

Existe alguna herramienta mediante la cual yo pueda ver como esta llegando mi request?

Es decir que la herramienta me de una url a la cual enviar mi request y yo recibir ese request y mediante una interfaz grafica ver lo que estoy enviando.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Postman es tu amigo:

https://www.getpostman.com/downloads/

Con postman puedes hacer llamadas a una API, Webservice, simular endopoints etc etc